# Resolve generic Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T> with Unity - get InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, unity-container, serilog, .net-core-logging

I am trying to register a generic ILogger (from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, not from Serilog) in Unity (version 4).

I've got the following class:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<MyClass> _logger;

    public MyClass(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

And the following Unity registrations and test:

```cs
// Arrange
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

// provider from Serilog.Extensions.Logging nuget package
var provider = new Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLoggerProvider();

container.RegisterType(typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<>),
    new InjectionFactory((ctr, type, name) =>
    {
        var loggerType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0].FullName;
        Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger = provider.CreateLogger(loggerType);
        return logger;
    }));

container.RegisterType<MyClass, MyClass>(); // just for demo purpose. 

// Assert
container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

This seems OK to me, too bad I am having the following error when resolving:

> Exception is: InvalidCastException - Unable to cast object of type 'Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLogger' to type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[MyNamespace.MyClass]'.

How to fix this issue?

Full exception:

> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MyNamespace.MyClass", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: Resolving parameter "logger" of constructor MyNamespace.MyClass(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[[MyNamespace.MyClass, MyNamespace.Infra.UnitTests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=edbaf8e9a324553f]] logger).
>   Exception is: InvalidCastException - Unable to cast object of type 'Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLogger' to type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[MyNamespace.MyClass]'.

### Update

when using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, this works:

```cs
// Arrange
var serviceCollection = new Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection()
    .AddLogging(builder => builder.AddSerilog())
    .AddTransient<MyClass, MyClass>();

var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

// Assert
serviceProvider.GetService<MyClass>();
```

So I try to get this working with Unity instead of Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Unfortunately there is no `AddSerilog` for Unity and I'm bound to Unity

Comment: `container.RegisterType<MyClass, MyClass>();` shouldn't this be something like container.RegisterType<IMyClass, MyClass>();? Dependency-Injections normaly are done requesting an Interface, not a class.

Comment: `container.RegisterType<MyClass, MyClass>()` is for the demo, the issue is the `ILogger<MyClass> ` resolve.

Comment: Did you try it with an `interface` Registered to a `class`? Resolving perhaps has a problem, becuase it has no interface..

Comment: Try instead `private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _logger;` and `public MyClass(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger logger)`.  You are creating a non-specialized logger in your injection configuration, so that of course will not be assignable to a specialized one.

Comment: @kara yes, the same issue is there with an interface (IMyClass for example)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch the goal is here to create the generic Logger. Non-generic does work (but needs another registation). Please note that generic loggers are advised by MS. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/ (note this case isn't ASP.NET Core)

Comment: CreateLogger does not create a generic logger though...

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch true, but the funny thing that this kinda works with ASP.NET Core (by using loggingProvider and loggingFactory). See usage/source https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging. There are generic ILoggers resolved with the same SerilogLoggerProvider

Comment: No, not the same.  They create a serilog provider using the logger type, you're creating a logger provider without a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this with the help of `MakeGenericMethod` and a helper method:

```cs
private static ILogger<T> CreateLogger<T>(ILoggerFactory factory)
{
    return new Logger<T>(factory);
}
```

And the final code (without reflection caching etc):

```cs
// Arrange
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

var logfactory = new LoggerFactory();

var provider = new Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLoggerProvider();
logfactory.AddProvider(provider);

container.RegisterType(typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<>),
    new InjectionFactory((ctr, type, name) =>
    {
        var loggerType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        var myType = this.GetType();

        var createLoggerMethod1 = myType.GetMethod(nameof(CreateLogger),BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        var createLoggerMethod = createLoggerMethod1.MakeGenericMethod(loggerType);

        var logger = createLoggerMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] {logfactory});

        return logger;
    }));

container.RegisterType<MyClass, MyClass>();

// Assert
container.Resolve<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I have found is to register a factory and reflect their extension method to do it and get the right response type.   This example also expects that you have registered an ILoggerFactory.

```
_container = new UnityContainer();
_container.RegisterInstance<ILoggerFactory>(new LoggerFactory().AddLog4Net(), new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
_container.RegisterFactory(typeof(ILogger<>), null, (c, t, n) =>
        {
            var factory = c.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>();
            var genericType = t.GetGenericArguments().First();
            var mi = typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactoryExtensions).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "CreateLogger" && m.IsGenericMethodDefinition);
            var gi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(t.GetGenericArguments().First());
            return gi.Invoke(null, new[] { factory });
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

[Unity.Microsoft.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Microsoft.Logging/) has a [LoggingExtension](https://github.com/unitycontainer/microsoft-logging/blob/master/src/LoggingExtension.cs) class that makes this fairly simple to achieve:

```cs
var loggerProvider = new SerilogLoggerProvider();
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create((builder) => builder.AddProvider(loggerProvider));
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.AddExtension(new LoggingExtension(loggerFactory));
```

Either of the following should now work:

```cs
container.Resolve<ILogger<MyClass>>();
container.Resolve<ILogger>(nameof(MyClass));
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there's already a Logger<T> implementation that takes an ILoggerFactory as a dependency you can just do

```cs
container.RegisterType<ILoggerFactory, MyLoggerFactory>();
container.RegisterType(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
container.Resolve<ILogger<MyClass>>();
```