# Prism Unity Register NLog as Microsoft.Extension.Logging.ILogger<T>

Tags: wpf, prism, unity-container, nlog

I have a shared Code between my backend and my frontend(WPF), where be backend currently uses NReco.Logging.File which is compatible with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.
But in the fronend, I use NLog.
Now I want to provide a NLog.Logger, every time when a ILogger is requested using Constructor.
Therefore I need to find a solution to setup the Prism.DI accordingly.

Currently I found the NLog.Extension.Hosting and NLog.Extensions.Logging, which registers NLog for Microsoft.Extension.Hosting.
https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/tree/master
Additionally I found the following Entry, for registering Serilog as ILog Provider:
[Resolve generic Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger<T> with Unity - get InvalidCastException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55573065/resolve-generic-microsoft-extensions-logging-iloggert-with-unity-get-invalid)

Is there any way to register NLog to Prism Unity to provide as Microsoft.Extension.Logging.ILogger.

Comment: can you expand on what exactly is the problem? the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70828207/5758420) you linked looks like it should work out of the box with NLog.Extensions.Logging

Comment: Yes, it works, but only when using Microsoft.Extension.Hosting as DI, but my Prism WPF Application uses the Unity DI. Therefore the Extensions don't fit.

Comment: My target is as already described above, that I want to setup Unity to return a NLog.Logger when a class requests one using constructor

Comment: What error are you getting, with what code?

Comment: you're aware that the extension you linked is an extension for the unity container?

Comment: If you mean the 2nd, that a Extension for Microsoft.Extension.Hosting, as far as I see.

Comment: And yes the Link to the Questing on Stackoverflow, is using Unity, but it is using Serilog instead of NLog, this was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the whole answer of the the other questing again, I could solve the problem the following way.

```
public static IContainerRegistry AddLogger(this IContainerRegistry services)
{
    var loggerFactory = new NLogLoggerFactory();
    var provider = new NLogLoggerProvider();
    loggerFactory.AddProvider(provider);
    services.RegisterInstance<ILoggerFactory>(loggerFactory);
    services.Register(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
    return services;
}
```

So now, all request go for ILogger are resolved with NLogger.

```
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.3.3"/>
```

Comment: Excellent choice to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`, and then just setup NLog as Logging-provider. Notice the `NLogLoggerFactory` default-constructor initializes itself with a default-provider, so no need to create `NLogLoggerProvider` and call `AddProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `AddNLog` from [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging)-nuget-package with help from [Prism.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Extensions/). By updating `App.xaml.cs` like this:

```cs
public partial class App : PrismApplication 
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddNLog();
            });
        });
    } 
}
```

Then a window can acquire `Microsoft.Extension.Logging.ILogger` using dependency injection like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ILogger<MainWindow> _logger;
 
    public MainWindow(ILogger<MainWindow> logger)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _logger = logger;
    }
 
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Hello");
    }
}
```